# how to call a function from a dropdown menu in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

** I ve two functions in my component.ts. 
1) getfixedbyId(val) 
2) getFloatById(val). 
but I'm not able to call them through this method. Dont want to use controllers.**

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="propertyId">
  <option value="">--Select Property -- </option>
    <ng-container *ngIf="subForm.controls.subscriptiondetails.controls.selecttype.value==='Somethging1'" ng-click="getFloatByID(property.someId)">
      <option *ngFor="let property of floatList" [(value)]="property.floatingId"  >{{property.name}}</option>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="subForm.controls.subscriptiondetails.controls.selecttype.value==='Something2'" ng-click="getFixedByID(property.someId)">
      <option *ngFor="let property of fixedList" [(value)]="property.fixedId" >{{property.name}}</option>
   </ng-container>

 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old AngularJS syntax for the click action. You should use the new Angular syntax like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="subForm.controls.subscriptiondetails.controls.selecttype.value==='Somethging1'" (click)="getFloatByID(property.someId)">
```

If you need more information about it you can read all about the click syntax in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/user-input).

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your way of calling a method in Angular like this -

```
ng-click
```

with

```
(click)
```

Comment: Still its not working. i ve kept a message in component file but its printing anything.